# trying to position my checkbox above the keyboard in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-linearlayout

My activity looks like this:

[image]

I use this XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5b74a8"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="7">

    </SearchView>

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:src="@drawable/settingsicon"
            android:background="@drawable/ambuttonstatessettings"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="settingsPopUp"
            />

</LinearLayout>

    <ListView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"></ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

But I want it to look like this, with a checkbox above the keyboard. Or if the keyboard is not there, the checkbox should be at the bottom :

[image]

Any idea how I can do this ? I tried this code, which is the closest I've come (basically, making a new linear layout at the bottom) but I can't get it right. And can't figure out why.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <SearchView
        android:layout_width="0px"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#5b74a8"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:id="@+id/searchView"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="7">

    </SearchView>
        <!--android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"-->
    <!--android:queryHint="howdy"-->

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:src="@drawable/settingsicon"
            android:background="@drawable/ambuttonstatessettings"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="settingsPopUp"
            />

</LinearLayout>

    <ListView

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/contacts_list"></ListView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:background="#ffa500"
            android:text="New CheckBox"
            android:id="@+id/checkBox"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Does your manifest have `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` for that activity?

Comment: You may need to use a relative layout but first try adjustresize setting as mentioned above

Comment: Yes, I have adjustresize in my manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SearchView
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#5b74a8"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:id="@+id/searchView"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_weight="7"/>

        <!--android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"-->
        <!--android:queryHint="howdy"-->

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/settingsButton"
            android:background="#787878"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:onClick="settingsPopUp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100">


        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="80"
            android:id="@+id/contacts_list"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <CheckBox
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:background="#ffa500"
                android:text="New CheckBox"
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

this is the solution.